# pygame - How to split the X and Y coordinates from get_pos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, coordinates

Sorry for all these questions, I really don't mean to bother you guys.

But the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to split the `X` and `Y` coordinates from the pygame `get_pos` function, as `get_pos` gets the `X` and `Y` coordinates in one.

**Is there a way to split them into separate variables?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`get_pos` returns a tuple. You can do a sequence unpacking:

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

To quote a great man (and Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)):

> This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for
>   any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires the
>   list of variables on the left to have the same number of elements as
>   the length of the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is really
>   just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking

Comment: I wish I could have chosen EVERYONE as the answer, however this was the first one lol :P

Answer (score 5):

get_pos returns an array/tuple of two values

so you could do something like this:

```
X,Y = 0,1
p = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse_pos = Vec2d(p[X],p[Y])
```

or even more simply

```
x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Also, this [page](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) has a button that lets you search for examples of the functions you're interested in.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and the handy website to check for examples.

Answer (score 3):

If its a tuple, can't you just unpack it like

```
x, y = get_pos()
```

Comment: I would just like to thank-you for the prompt reply. I wish I could choose everyone as the answer.

Comment: @monkey334 Well, the others made it more clearly for your `pygame` case, where as I know that only by name. Your're welcome.